how to remove suggestions bar from the virtual keyboard
I'm creating a PWA (Progressive Web App), but in Android Chrome, the suggestions bar on the virtual keyboard is messing up my layout (See image). It is overlaping with important buttons that are bellow the text input. Other mobile browsers do not have this problem.

In the Samsung Browser:

How can I remove this suggestions bar, or find a way for chrome to not overlap the keyboard with the existing button?
I tried using CSS env variables like keyboard-inset-height with no success.

see this

This question is similar to: Prevent Android keyboard in Chrome from showing password management on HTML input. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
